# Running multiple commands at the same time in a script shell

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I just created this script to run the following commands all together at the same time:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/me/Desktop/folder/app1
sudo service mongod start
grunt dev
cd ../app2
npm start
cd ../app3
npm start
http-server
sudo service nginx restart
```

but it only runs the first three lines .. help please

Comment: Shell scripts run the commands sequentially, not in parallel.  I'm not familiar with `grunt`, but I suspect it is not written to daemonize, so you need to background it either with `&` or with an application-specific flag.  What happens if you execute `grunt dev` at the command line?  Are you returned a prompt or does the prompt not return until you cause the `grunt` process to exit?

Comment: `grunt dev` can be replaced with `npm start` , its perks are that changes that we make are updated instantly, so we use it instead of corrupting `npm start` and rerunning it

Comment: For the other `cd` commands I would have the absolute paths.